# How can I use more than one Stored Procedure in a crystal report?

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

I have two stored procedures and the data of those two procedures is not related to each other. I want show the all data from those two stored procedures in one crystal reports. And also I want to display the data from two procedures one after the other. Can anyone help me to solve this problem?

Comment: hi prasanna, can you share the two stored procedure schema

Answer (score 0, accepted):

prasanna, you have to use Sub report as suggested by ajit or you can merge both stored procedure data in one Datatable or DataSet in code behind :)

Comment: Thank you all for your answers. Added sub reports. It worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can create use as many stored procedures you want on a single report. As a best practice and more because two sub-reports usually return unrelated data, it is advisable to insert Sub-reports for each stored procedure.